# Sonarqube, PMD, findbugs and checkstyle

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using sonarqube community version 6.7.2, and, as I remember, SonarJava plugin was aiming to replace (mostly at least) Findbugs and PMD rules by squid ones. There was an information on rules from those providers when there was a proper squid rule replacement, but now I am unable to find it and some rules from findbugs, for example, are very similar to others I know from squid.

Sonarqube recommends using only squid rules? Does those rules replaces well rules from PMD and Findbugs?

Comment: Hi, I don't think stackoverflow is really suited for such question: I think it would be nicer to open a thread on https://community.sonarsource.com 
And for comparison of rules, I am really biaised here (I wrote quite some rules of SonarJava) so I would say, at least we aimed to reimplement when it makes sense and improve where we can, so I am tempted to answer : Yes, and they are even better, but test for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to use squid rules because they are supported by [SonarLint](https://www.sonarlint.org/).

Unfortunately, there is no available a rules mapping which allows you to easily migrate from Checkstyle, FindBugs or PMD to SonarJava plugin (it was, but has been dropped: [Where is dist.sonarsource.com content?](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/where-is-dist-sonarsource-com-content/5353?u=agabrys)).

Comment: All these links are broken.  It appears SonarSource has stopped being transparent when it comes to comparing their analyzer to the tried-and-true open-source tools mentioned in the OP question.